# Restoring AWS S3 bucket using s3-pit-restore

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, restore

When trying to perform a point-in-time restore of an S3 bucket to another bucket using [s3-pit-restore](https://github.com/madisoft/s3-pit-restore), I get a syntax error pointing to the name of the source bucket. Here is my command, issued at a Python prompt on Windows 7:

```
s3-pit-restore -b mybucketeu -d mybucketeubak -t "11-27-2017 11:00:00 -6"
```

The syntax error prompt points to the final character of mybucketeu.

I am not very experienced with AWS CLI but got it installed and configured so that I can get a list of buckets including the two buckets above. Python 3.6 and s3-pit-restore installed without apparent issues

Our ultimate goal is to be able to roll back everything in an S3 bucket to a point in time with exactly the same contents as existed then.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The url that you have provided is not working, though I found another one [here](https://github.com/angeloc/s3-pit-restore).

If you are following the above link, then it clearly states

With this tool you can easily restore a repository to a point in time with a simple command like:

> ```
> To local file-system:
>
>  $ s3-pit-restore -b my-bucket -d restored-bucket-local -t "06-17-2016 23:59:50 +2"
>
> To s3 bucket:-
>
>  $ s3-pit-restore -b my-bucket -B restored-bucket-s3 -t "06-17-2016 23:59:50 +2"
> ```

So in your case use -B

```
s3-pit-restore -b mybucketeu -B mybucketeubak -t "11-27-2017 11:00:00 -6"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem as I was running the command from within my AWS Sagemaker notebook. The problem was fixed by adding an `!` to the beginning of the command. So for you it could be:

```
!s3-pit-restore -b mybucketeu -d mybucketeubak -t "11-27-2017 11:00:00 -6"
```