# Use s3-pit-restore - not recongized as an internal or external command

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, backup, point-in-time-recovery

Using project: https://github.com/angeloc/s3-pit-restore

**S3-pit-restore** seems like a useful point-in-time restore tool for Amazon S3. I followed the provided instructions to install this tool on Windows 10 Pro. Python and AWS CLI are running without any problems. s3-pit-restore files are residing in the same directory as Python, and the path is already set. It is not working for me.

[Restoring AWS S3 bucket using s3-pit-restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518987/restoring-aws-s3-bucket-using-s3-pit-restore) discussed another issue. I am stuck on installation of this tool

The following steps are taken:

1. An AWS CLI profile was created and tested. It is working.
2. `pip3 install s3-pit-restore`
3. Customize the provided command according to my needs.

Error message on the command line:

> 's3-pit-restore' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Have anyone run this code successfully on a Windows 10 environment? Please let me know with the exact steps. I am feeling that new version of this code will only run in a Linux environment.
Secondly, do you know any tool that can help achieve point-in-time file restoration from AWS S3?

Following [Point-in-time restore for Amazon S3 buckets | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/point-in-time-restore-for-amazon-s3-buckets/), I didn't get the desired result. I am still in the process of customizing it.

Comment: What is the command you ran that resulted in that error message? I suspect that instead of running `s3-pit-restore` from the Command Line, you should run `python3 s3-pit-restore`

Comment: The s3-pit-restore package installs a single [python script](https://github.com/angeloc/s3-pit-restore/blob/master/s3-pit-restore), and does not install the OS specific stubs to run it on non-Unix operating systems.  You might be able to run the script directly either by downloading it or finding it installed on your local machine simply by running `python s3-pit-restore`.

Comment: Great. After adding Python to the command, it is working fine for me. Thank you, @JohnRotenstein and Anon Coward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the error:

> 's3-pit-restore' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This indicates that the Windows command-line cannot find a program called `s3-pit-restore`.

Therefore, try running:

```
python3 s3-pit-restore
```

If you were on Linux instead of Windows, you could `chmod +x` the script and then it would work fine because the first line of the file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This tells Linux where to find the executable. This doesn't translate well to Windows.